# micronaut multivalued form field support?

Tags: field, multivalue, micronaut

If I send this form to Micronaut with method='GET' then I can extract param1 as a list of two values ... aaa and bbb

```
<form action='/test/post' method='GET' >
    <input type='hidden' name='param1' value = 'aaa'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='param1' value = 'bbb'/>            
    <input type='submit' value='Post'/> 
</form>
```

If however I post it and use the method(@Body Map params) and

```
    consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED
```

on the server side only the last value ('bbb') is seen. The same is true if I encode with multipart/form-data instead.

Is this a bug or a feature of Micronaut 1.0.0 ?

Comment: Can you show what the request body is in both of the failure cases?

Comment: @James - In the x-www-form-urlencoded case it is

param1=aaa&param1=bbb

and in the multipart/form-data it is

------WebKitFormBoundaryTRQB1iFcEg1bdcMa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param1"

aaa
------WebKitFormBoundaryTRQB1iFcEg1bdcMa
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param1"

bbb
------WebKitFormBoundaryTRQB1iFcEg1bdcMa--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that will be handled in the next release

PR submitted: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/pull/899

Comment: Great -- looking forward to it. Tnx